# Wordpress - Password Protected Page White Page after login

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site and its running Wordpress 5.7 and I have 2 password protected pages and when I goto login to these pages I get a white screen after logging in. The URL that I get redirected to is: `/wp-login.php?action=postpass` I have tried the following solutions:

- Download a fresh version of Wordpress and replaced wp-login.php on my site with the fresh one.
- Deactivated all my plugins
- Deactivated my theme and switched to the default one (Twenty Nineteen)

And none of those worked, anyone got any other solution to this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: White screen suggests you're encountering an error with error output switched off. Set WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG to true in your wp-config.php file (https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log) and navigate to the page where you're seeing the issue. Once you have details in the log, please post.

Comment: WP_DEBUG is set to true and I even have error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); still nothing.

Comment: Do you have the log enabled (writing to a log file rather than outputting on the page)]?

Comment: I don't think I do, how do I do that?

Comment: Did you try to access the page with an other browser ? It might be related to the Referrer-Policy HTTP header.

Comment: I also have the site on wordpress and then I go to `/wp-login.php?action=postpass` this page it's also white screen, maybe it's should be?

Comment: @Dmitry this is proper behaviour. You have to access `/wp-login.php?action=postpass` not directly but from a page, having HTTP_REFERER (see my answer).

Answer (score 6):

It is hard to say exactly what is going on with such limited information. Analysis of the code in `wp-login.php` shows that the described issue could happen if there is no `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in the request. I have reproduced the issue adding

```
unset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
```

before line 650

```
$referer = wp_get_referer();
```

in `wp-login.php`.

To check that the issue is related to the referrer, please try to insert the line

```
var_dump( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
```

before the same line 650 in `wp-login.php` (and don't forget to remove it later), and let me know the output - you have to see it on the white screen.

It seems to me you will have the following message:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_REFERER" in ...\wp-login.php on line 650
NULL
```

The question is - why don't you have a referrer here.

Browser does not provide a referrer doing the HTTP request from an HTTPS page. If the site was moved to HTTPS incorrectly, the form can contain the `action` field with `http:`.

Some browser extensions can also make tricks. Please deactivate all of them.

Comment: And no reaction at all... I wonder why people ask questions, mark them as very important by the bounty and simply do not read answers.

Comment: Sorry, I got busy with stuff and this was a low priority that I have been working on for awhile, couldn't figured it out so I posted it on here...I will try your solution later today, thank you for your answer

Comment: @KAGGDesign I have the same issue as the question creator and inserted your code line. I now see ```NULL``` on the white screen...

Comment: I just set the variable by adding ```<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="'.get_permalink().'" />``` into the form tag of the output of ```get_the_password_form()``` function in wp-includes/post-template.php (line 1726 for me) (described by @shoaibhaibtan in his answer). This works but it seems kind of dirty and not intended by wordpress...

Answer (score 2):

Since August 2020, Chrome and other browsers STARTED rolling [a tighter referrer policy with a default to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6251880185331712).

> Web developers may specify a referrer policy on their documents, which impacts the `Referer` header sent on outgoing requests and navigations. When no policy is specified, Chrome will now use `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` as the default policy, instead of `no-referrer-when-downgrade`.

Adding  with `no-referrer-when-downgrade` should supposedly force a referrer downgrade to it's previous status.

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
```

(Even tho that might fix it, it might not be the best option, as it might become mandatory in a near/far future to roll with a tighter one, as law changes in regards to privacy across countries).

Tho the impact is supposed to be limited, you might be falling under that category. And you're not the only one.

> Based on [discussions](https://github.com/privacycg/proposals/issues/13#issuecomment-622029248) with other browsers and Chrome's own experimentation run in Chrome 84, user-visible breakage is expected to be limited.

A complete in-details post as been published by the beautiful people at Google, [don't hesitate to take a look](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default). They have a section, ["If this impacts your site, consider alternatives"](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default#if_this_impacts_your_site_consider_alternatives).

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem to solve my issue i go to wp-includes/post-template.php

and search the funciton get_the_password_form()

and add this

`<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="'.get_permalink().'" />`

after $output
and also add this ( apply_filters( 'the_password_form', $output );
return $output; )

it is work for me

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Then noticed that we have the domain in wordpress with www. but they set a link to the protected page without www. When I enter the password without www it gets redirected to the domain without www and have no cookie for this domain, thus not logged in and white page. I added a redirect from non www to www domain in htaccess to be sure the domain is correct and it worked!